# HELO handshake error?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am really new to all this mail server administration and I dont know much...
Soo my problem is that some mail servers are rejecting my newsletter with reason:

The mail system

```
<example@example.com>: delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with
    server.example.com[123.45.67.89] while performing the HELO handshake

Final-Recipient: rfc822; example@example.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;example@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.2
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection
    with server.example.com[123.45.67.89] while performing the HELO handshake.
```

Soo does anyone knows what am I doing wrong, and how can I repair it? Any help is really appreciated...

Best regards
Mrky

Comment: You probably need to have proper DNS and RDNS entries for your server, could you post the output of `postconf -n`  ?

Comment: I tried to paste it here, but it was not accepted :(

Answer (score 1):

- Check to see if you're on any of the RBL blacklists.  If you're trying to send from your home ADSL connection, or have been responsible for spam in the past, you are more or less guaranteed to be blocked by a lot of mail servers.

  http://spameatingmonkey.com/lookup
  http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/

Servers may also maintain their own private blacklists of course.

- Make sure that you have a working reverse DNS entry for your IP, which points to a name which resolves back to your IP.
- A significant number of servers will also block you on the basis of your not strictly following the SMTP protocol.  Eg if you send the HELO line before the remote server sends it's greeting.

Other than that, there's not too many reasons for servers to block you before you have sent them any information.  I'm not 100% certain though from the error message whether the remote servers are blocking you before or after you send the HELO line.

- If they block you after the HELO line is sent, you should consider what HELO line you are using.  Are you sending a valid, publicly available fully qualified domain name, which resolves back to the IP you are connecting to these remote servers from?  It's best if it also matches the PTR record for your IP, though this is not usually a criteria for outright blocking a connection.

Comment: I checked and I am not on any RBL blacklist, I know problem is somewere in MX or RDNS... Can you tell me how RDNS should look like and how can I check how my HELO looks like?

Comment: It's very useful to learn to use tools like tcpdump and ngrep to look at the network traffic directly, but as a one-off it's probably easier to have a good look at the mail headers of messages that are being successfully delivered.  The format of the 'Received' headers varies a lot depending on what mail software is involved, but the HELO header is often shown.  The PTR record for your IP must exist, and it must point to a domain name which resolves back to your IP.  that domain name is usually the same one you use in your HELO greeting.

Answer (score 0):

Do they reject it only once or always ? - problem is, such closed connections are a frequent event on spam-filtering.

Comment: They are rejectin it always, I know I have some problem with MX records or RDNS but I am not sure what, my ex colegue set that mail server and left company, and I am tottaly noob for this matter :(